# Fractional N Synthesis and Frequency Meters

Tags: frequency-measurement, frequency-synthesis

**I Updated the question *twice* at the bottom**

I bought a 30-year-old frequency meter from EBay. It has the ultra-stable OCXO reference option, but hasn't been calibrated in 9 years.
[image: Racal Dana 1998]
It seemed to work straight away so I fed it from the Arbitrary Waveform Generator of a [Picoscope 4262](https://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope/4262/picoscope-4262-overview) to try out some of the functions. The AWG uses a fractional-N synthesiser to generate its internal clock.

Then I started to worry that the meter was faulty.[image: picture of digits in readout]
Sitting looking at the  meter, it flashed its Gate LED and updated the display once a second. Mostly it just changed digit 8 or 9 in the above picture - the AWG isn't especially stable. But sometimes, maybe one update in 5, digit 7 would not change, digits 8 and 9 would not change much, but digit 6 would hop up or down by 1. I was measuring frequency at about 19 kHz and the "19" was in digits 1 and 2.

Then I tried a packaged 20Mhz crystal oscillator. I let it warm up for some hours and watched the display: rock solid. It drifted slowly as the oscillator temperature changed but that was all.

Then I acquired an [M5Stack M003 GPS module](https://shop.m5stack.com/products/gps-module). This uses a [u-blox NEO M8N](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/neo-m8-series) GPS chip, and inside that there is a fractional N synthesiser to generate an output clock, locked to GPS sources. I programmed it to generate 10 MHz. Again I see a digit change on the meter. Digit 9 stays the same, or varies by 1, and digit 8 jumps up and down by 2 units.
Then switch to 1 MHz. Again digit 9 stays the same and digit 8 jumps by 2. Then I reduce the meter resolution, so it uses a shorter gate time. Now digit 7 jumps up and down by 2 and digit 8 stays the same. Then back to the 20 MHz crystal source: rock solid, no jumping.

I find it hard to imagine what could be going on with the sources that happen to use fractional-N synthesis that would cause one particular digit of the meter to jump value. Any ideas, please?

**Update 1**

It occurred to me that this meter cannot just be counting pulses in the gate time, because it displays 0.1 Hz resolution for a 10 MHz signal in a 1 s gate time. It must be measuring the time between the input pulse edges and the gate edges somehow.

And indeed it does. I found the maintenance manual online. It says:

> The measurement circuits of the instrument are provided by three custom-built integrated circuits. These are the two Multiple Counter and Control (MCC) circuits, MCC1 and MCC2, and the Timing Error Correction (TEC) circuit. A block diagram is shown in Fig 6.5.

> The circuits within MCC1 and MCC2 are configured by the microprocessor according to the measurement function in use. The recipromatic counting technique is used. With this technique the measured signal, not the counter clock pulses, controls the start and stop of the measurement period (gate time) as shown in Fig 6.6.

> The gate time therefore extends over an integral number of cycles of the measured waveform. The gate time is measured by counting the clock pulses which occur while the gate is open. This leads to timing errors at both ends of the gate time, as shown. The TEC circuit enhances the measurement accuracy by compensating for these errors.

[image: circuit block diagram]
The input frequency is divided by two before being counted. So if the meter counts 5,000,000 pulses in 1,000,000,050 ns, it will read out 9.9999995 MHz. And if the meter counts 4,999,999 pulses in the same time, it will read out 9.9999975 MHz. This is a change of 2 in the penultimate digit, which is what is observed. And this also explains how the digit which is affected changes with gate time and input range.

Of course, the meter shouldn't count 4,999,999 pulses: it seems to have dropped one somewhere. But why only for the synthesised clocks? It may be something to do with jitter. But actually all the clocks show jitter in the 500 ps range. Yet the crystal source does not show this jump-by-two-digits behaviour.

**Updated Again**

I experimented with measuring 5 kHz signals from the Picoscope AWG again. As I change the frequency meter resolution, it changes its gate time, and changes the number of digits it displays. The number of digits it gives is consistent with a 10ns resolution in the timing error correction circuit. As I increase the number of displayed digits, it is always the rightmost displayed digit that is changing. That's because adding 1 digit to the display multiplies the gate time by a factor of ten, and a fixed uncertainty in the timing error correction gives a ten times smaller error in the readout.

By chance, I switched the AWG to square wave output, and the frequency meter went crazy, displaying either 4571.5 Hz or 4552.7 Hz, randomly. Looking with the scope, I could see that the AWG has a bug (very beta software) and had jitter of about 5μs on some cycles, although the frequency was actually correct at 4567.0 Hz. That was with a 1ms gate time. The meter will be measuring only 6 cycles of the input then. Those two frequency readouts correspond to a gate time measurement of either 1.3125 ms or 1.3179 ms, a difference of 5.4 μs. Looking with the scope at the jitter in some cycles, I see a jitter of 5.6 μs.

The measurement I described earlier, where the penultimate display digit changed by 2, is consistent with the timing error correction circuit changing its output by 25 ns. I don't know if that is the resolution of the digital circuit but it is not infeasible.

All this is consistent with the meter's architecture causing it to be particularly sensitive to jitter on its input edges. The two fractional-n synthesised sources I tried happened to be slightly jittery, and I guess the crystal source was not. I think the meter is working as it was designed to, but I must remember in future that it can be confused by jitter.

Thanks very much to everyone who has made suggestions! I think I understand this now, and I'm off to try something else to confuse me.

Answer (score 1):

On a 19kHz frequency, if your gate time is one second, then most of the time it will count 19000 cycles... and sometimes it will count 18999 or 19001, depending if the 19kHz oscillator is slightly off towards higher or lower frequency relative to the instrument clock, how the edges align with the gate time, etc.

If the instrument is perfectly accurate, and the 19000 frequency is actually 19000.5 then it will count 19000 or 19001 with about 50/50 chance.

Basically, if you use an integration time T to measure a frequency F, you'll get F*T +/-1 pulses, and that's the maximum accuracy you can get.

So when you use a shorter integration time, the digit that flips moves, it's expected. In fact the instrument should blank the non-significant digits.

**EDIT**

[How fractional-N PLL works](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra029/swra029.pdf).

[image]

That's an integer PLL: it divides the VCO output by a constant N, compares the phase and frequency of that to the incoming clock, and adjusts the VCO control voltage to make it slower/faster accordingly.

In a fractional-N PLL, the divider ratio is dynamically switched between two consecutive values in a proportion that makes the desired average division ratio.

This is the kind of stuff that looks crazy at first. But there's a simple reason why it works. The two divider values are swapped very often, ideally at a much faster frequency than the bandwidth of the loop filter.

Say you got 10MHz at the XO input, you want 10.1 MHz at the output. Suppose your VCO likes running in the 300-600MHz range. It would be nice to run the VCO at 494.9Mhz, then divide that by 49 with the output divider (not shown in the picture) to get 10.1MHz.

Now, 494.9MHz is 49.49 times 10MHz, so the N-divider in the loop (shown in the picture with label "divide by N") should be set to 49.49, in other words, it should flip between 49 and 50 about half the time each.

When it is set to 49, its output frequency will be too **high**, so the phase-frequency detector (PFD) will correct by trying to **lower** the VCO frequency.

When it is set to 50, its output frequency will be too **low**, so the phase-frequency detector (PFD) will correct by trying to **raise** the VCO frequency.

This means the output of the PFD is going to look like a bit of a square wave: faster... slower... faster... slower...

If the two ratios flip often enough (ideally after one complete count) then they will flip every 50+49=99 VCO cycles, or every 200ns, a frequency of 5MHz. If your loop filter has a reasonably low cutoff, say a few tens of kHz, this will be greatly attenuated, and the filter will feed the VCO with a smooth almost constant voltage. So the VCO's output frequency will be very clean and stable.

However, if the fractional division ratio is not 49.5, but instead something like 49.001 then it will have to do 999 cycles at N=49 and 1 cycle at N=50. So now, the frequency of the "faster... slower..." pulses at the output is much lower, the loop filter will be less effective at smoothing it, the VCO will receive a sawtooth control voltage, and the output frequency will wobble.

To avoid this you're supposed to set the input and output dividers of the Frac-N PLL, and pick a VCO frequency that gives you a nice fractional division ratio, as close as possible to one half between two integers, so it flips between the two values very often and the loop filter can do its thing. Usually the manufacturer gives a cryptic snippet of code to generate the most appropriate configuration values for any output frequency.

So to summarize, referring to your question: yes, a Frac-N PLL can produce a wobbly or unstable frequency, but if that happens, that would indicate an improper choice of parameters. I don't think this is what you're observing here.

The proper way to check if a frequency is stable would be with a spectrum analyzer or a phase noise analyzer  .

The ghetto way is to pick a known stable oscillator at a frequency not further than 20-40kHz from the DUT oscillator. Then you mix the two and get a signal with the difference between both frequencies. In a pinch, a logic gate like AND, NAND, OR, XOR... works fine. Then you either listen to it, or analyze it with a PC soundcard. If both frequencies are stable, you get a nice spike on the FFT. If one frequency is moving around, then the difference also moves around, and the FFT gives a wider spectrum with skirts and all sorts of detail that give information about what the problem is.

Since you have two Frac-N PLLs, an experiment you can do is set them to the same frequency and display both on the scope, with the trigger set to one of them. So, one waveform will be stable on the screen, and the other which is at a slightly different frequency will sweep left to right. Then you adjust the frequency precisely so the moving waveform matches the frequency of the other. Then it should stay still on the screen, or move very slowly relative to the one on the trigger. If its frequency drifts or wobbles, you will see it, it's very "visual", it will shake left to right or begin sweeping again. Since one of your oscillators is probably not an OCXO, it should exhibit enough thermal drift that you can see them move relative to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's more complicated than that! I updated the question.

Comment: Does the manual say what the TEC circuit does?

Comment: It must measure the position of the reference clock with respect to the gate edges. To give a correction for the actual length of the gate. It could get a good resolution if it measured that to 10 ns. But my meter seems to be getting that wrong as the signal edges move.

Comment: Huh. I always thought that fractional-N meant the addition of a second frequency divider (say by a factor of M) either before or after the loop, so that the net output would be a frequency of N/M times the input frequency. Looks like it's more complicated than that--I assume to avoid my naïve method's inherently poor response speed to changing input frequencies.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like the post-divider on an integer PLL, it's needed because the VCO has a favorite frequency range, if you want lower on the output you have to use the divider, and it allows you to do non-integer ratios like multiply by 10 then divide by 3, but not with the flexibility of Frac-N

Answer (score 0):

Fractional-N synthesis means that we can digitally approximate division by a *non*-integer.  For example, we can divide by 26.7 by dividing by 26 some of the time, and dividing by 27 the rest of the time.  Both 26 and 27 are integers and easily possible.  So if we switch the divider rapidly between "divide by 26" and "divide by 27", the overall effect is to divide by a value between the two.  The exact value divided is dependent on the ratio (or duty cycle) of the switching.

But how do frequency counters work?  They count *edges* between a precisely-timed interval (or "window").  Each *edge* of the input waveform increases the count.  Before the window starts, the count is held at zero.  Once the window has started, counting is allowed freely.  When the window stops, the count is *held* and displayed on the LED digits.  And then the cycle will repeat again and again...

But the value you see is highly dependent upon the precise relationship of the input signal to the window.  If an input *edge* happens really close to the window start, it might, or might not, be counted.  Similarly an input *edge* may be close to the window-*end* and thus may or may not be counted.  So in practice, frequency counters are always variant in the last digit, which can vary plus or minus 1, just because of the random nature of the phasing of the input *edges* vs the counter's internal window.

But when driven from a fractional generator, it gets worse.  What if the window-end happens right after a division-by-27 segment?  The count will be a tad low as there are fewer counts dividing by 27 than by 26.  If the window-end happens right after a divide-by-26 segment, the count will be a little "high" for similar reasons.  I.e. the input frequency is not a constant; it is rapidly changing between two different frequencies.  The two different frequencies alternate at some fixed interval.  If the counter's window matches this interval, then the counter will always receive (and count) the correct number of 26 vs 27 segments, and its count will be pretty good.  *But* if the counter's window is "off" from that interval (i.e., a non-integral number of them), its displayed count will vary depending upon whether the window happened to pick up "more" of the 26's vs "more" of the 27s.  So it can vary.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not how fractional-N synthesis works. The frequency output is constant.

Comment: Thanks! I did originally hope that someone would explain some obscure detail of fractional-N synthesis, but now I don't think that is what is happening. I updated the question above.